# Tell the TypeScript compiler where to look for non-relative modules

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using ts-loader and Webpack to compile my .ts files. In My Webpack config I have the following configuration:

```
resolve: {
  modulesDirectories: ['shared', 'node_modules']
}
```

This allows me to import a component that lives in the shared directory without spelling out the full relative path. Example:

`import Button from 'components/Button'`

Webpack will walk up the directory tree looking for a `shared` directory. This way, the component can live in the `../../shared/components/Buttton.tsx` and Webpack will find it and bundle it.

This all works fine, however I am getting errors in my editors (both Sublime and VS Code). Also, if I run the `tsc` command from the command line I will get compiler errors because the TS compiler does not know how to resolve those modules.

Is there a way to tell the TS compiler to recursively look for the component in the `shared` directories?

I am using TS 2.1v

I noticed the new `BaseUrl` and `paths` configuration options but I was not able to use them successfully.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to tell the TS compiler to recursively look for the component in the shared directories

Not recursively. But you can go with one level using `paths` mapping.

Comment: I have a `shared` directory that contains all my css and components that are shared with other component. If I have a deeply nested component how can I import a shared component without referencing the relative path?